# Trying to insert images for visualizing description on the right

Tags: graphics, text

I am trying to write a description for a game. I have to explain some key elements and I wanted to illustrate this with images on the left side (image below).
This particular image has been made with InDesign, but I want to achieve exactly this in LateX. The articles describing the pictures are not very long, most of them not longer than to lines of text. It is important, that the images line up with their corresponding text.

How can I achieve this?

My Code:
(the important part is `\subsection{Bewegungsregeln einzelner Steine}` )

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,curves,float,rotating}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Regelwerk Hive}
\author{AUthor}
\date{22. Oktober 2018}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\pagestyle{headings}
\textwidth 15cm
\textheight 23cm
\oddsidemargin 1cm
\evensidemargin 0cm

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}



    \LARGE
    \textbf{Hive - Das Regelwerk} \\[2ex]
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{logo} \\[18ex]
    \textit{Author} \\[2ex]
    \Large
    22. Oktober 2018


\end{center}

\newpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\pagestyle{headings}

\section{Einleitung}
\label{einleitung}

Lorem

\subsection{Ziel des Spieles}

Lorem

\subsection{Spielmaterial}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=1]{spielsteine}
  \caption{Spielsteine in weiß und schwarz, sowie der schwarz-weiße Startstein}
  \label{fig:spielsteine}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

Lorem

\section{Regeln}
\label{regeln}

Lorem\\ \\

\subsection{Anlegen neuer Steine}
\begin{itemize}
\item Lorem
\item Lorem
\item Lorem
\item Lorem
\end{itemize}
\subsection{Bewegen bereits gelegter Steine}
\begin{itemize}
\item Lorem
\item Lorem
\item Lorem
\item Lorem
\end{itemize}



\subsection{Bewegungsregeln einzelner Steine}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{2cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{queen}
Description for the Queen
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{ant}
Descripton for the ant
\end{wrapfigure}




\section{Ende}
\label{ende}
Lorem ...

\end{document}
```

I tried minipages. But this way they are not aligned. The second image is a bit more to the right and the text is starting at the bottom line of the image

```
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{queen}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
The Queen can move [...]
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ant}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
The Ant can move [...]
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TEX SX! Could you post a minimal (yet complete, not a snippet) code?

Comment: I edited my post, but the codes doenst get formatted properly :/ I am not quite sure, what I did wrong, sorry
The importan part is \subsection{Bewegungsregeln einzelner Steine}. There I want to achieve this effect. I tried wrapfigure, but that only works for one image
Edit: Thank you Johannes_B for formatting the code!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I wouldn't use `titlesec` for the section headings and `wrapfigure` at all. I would rather work with `minipage`s and lists (as you already do).

Comment: Okay, I tried minipages and edited the post

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it to work now. The code with the minipages is almost correct, the only missing thing is a \hfill between every section, so that they are aligned